# boto3: Unable to find CloudFront keys using list_distributions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

According to the [boto3 documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.list_distributions), there should be the keys `HttpVersion` and `IsIPV6Enabled` when calling `list_distributions()`.

Running the following:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudfront')
dists = client.list_distributions()
dists['DistributionList']['Items'][0].keys()
```

Only lists the following keys:

```
[u'Status', u'CacheBehaviors', u'Restrictions', u'Origins', 
u'DomainName', u'WebACLId', u'PriceClass', u'Enabled', 
u'DefaultCacheBehavior', u'Comment', u'ViewerCertificate', 
u'CustomErrorResponses', u'LastModifiedTime', u'Id', u'ARN', u'Aliases']
```

Is the documentation incorrect or am I missing something here?

I'm doing this using Python 2.7.12 with boto3 (1.4.4) and botocore (1.5.4).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug with the data being sent for the response from AWS - after discussing with AWS Support it has been fixed.